# Search for nodes in a QDomDocument using XPath

Tags: c++, qt, xpath, qxmlquery, qdomdocument

I am spoiled (rotten, to be sure) by C# and its XML manipulation classes in the `System.Xml` namespace.  I can load an XML file into an `XmlDocument`.  I can search the whole document for nodes that match an XPath expression, using `XmlNode.SelectNodes( "an xpath expression" )`.  The result is an `XmlNodeList` that contains `XmlNode` objects that I can iterate over.

Now I am using C++ Qt (versions 4.7.1 and 4.8, but the particular version may not be important).  I can load an XML file into a `QDomDocument`.  But, I am frustrated that I cannot search the document using an XPath expression in a similar way that I did in C#.

I have had limited success using `QXmlQuery` to find stuff in the XML file.  If I write the query in just the right way, I can obtain a `QStringList` of results, iterate that `QStringList`, and then store the data somewhere for use later.

But, I still want to be able to obtain a collection of `QDomNode` objects that are in the document, directly via an XPath expression.  One specific use case is to find one element whose "name" attribute has a certain value, and then replace that element with a new element.  That is why I want the `QDomNode` object itself, not just some string-based or other representation of the XML content that `QXmlQuery` can provide.  For the specific use case just mentioned, I am getting by using `QDomElement.elementsByTagName()` and iterating those elements, but it is not as flexible nor as cool as XPath.

Is it just wishful thinking?  Would it be worth the effort to develop some new class that implements the `QAbstractXmlReceiver` interface?  Or, would I just end up with a new collection of data that has no direct relationship to the `QDomNode` objects in the `QDomDocument`?

Comment: It's very strange that being the design choice of Qt team to keep separate data models for DOM and XQuery/XPath/XSLT, they didn't fill the gap with some out of the box implementation of `QAbstractXmlNodeModel`. You can find one at  https://adared.ch/qdomnodemodel-qxmlquery/

Comment: Thank you, @Alejandro.  That was an excellent suggestion.  The `QDomNodeModel` source code available from that link, combined with the `QXmlQuery` usage example at  https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37645-QAbstractXmlNodeModel-implementation-QDomNodeModel-QXmlQuery, is sufficiently developed to work for me as-is.

Comment: Youre not spoiled. 15 years ago, I wrote a C application on AIX to parse large complex XML files following an absurd standard called ACORD. I used libxml and could do XPath anywhere from any node, it was a breeze.  Why an otherwise wonderful framework like QT would choose to leave this out is beyond me.  I agree, and although I see a pretty simple solution below, I now see that even that wont work with QT6. So, I'm thinking maybe just using libxml direct calls like I have in the past.  I'll see if I can get a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the utility function I use to search for nodes in a `QDomDocument` using an XPath expression.  It uses the `QDomNodeModel` class suggested by @Alejandro, downloadable from https://adared.ch/qdomnodemodel-qxmlquery.  It is based on the usage example from https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37645-QAbstractXmlNodeModel-implementation-QDomNodeModel-QXmlQuery.  Thanks to Stanislaw Adaszewski, who provided both the `QDomNodeModel` class and the usage example.

There are a few methods in `QDomNodeModel` that are commented as not implemented.  However, for the simple XML content that I needed to search, `QDomNodeModel` is sufficient as-is.

```
//
/// @brief Search for nodes in a QDomDocument using an XPath.
/// @note I cannot return a QDomNodeList, because it has no public methods for adding items to it.
/// @param[in] doc The document to search.
/// @param[in] fromNode The node in the document to start searching from.
///   e.g., to search the whole document, use <code>doc.documentElement()</code>.
/// @param[in] xpath The XPath expression.
/// @return A list of found nodes.
//
QList<QDomNode> findNodes( QDomDocument const & doc, QDomNode const & fromNode, QString const & xpath )
{
  qDebug( "%s", __FUNCTION__ );
  QList<QDomNode> foundNodes;

  //------------------------------
  // The name pool that everybody shares.
  QXmlNamePool pool;

  //------------------------------
  // The model that wraps the document.
  QDomNodeModel model( pool, doc );

  //------------------------------
  // The query.
  // XQuery10 means the default XQuery 1.0 language, as opposed to XSLT20.
  QXmlQuery query( /*QXmlQuery::XQuery10,*/ pool );

  // Operate on the given node.
  QXmlNodeModelIndex fromIndex = model.fromDomNode( fromNode );
  query.setFocus( QXmlItem( fromIndex ) );

  // The query statement.
  query.setQuery( xpath );
  if ( !query.isValid() )
  {
    qDebug( "Query is not valid" );
    return foundNodes;
  }

  //------------------------------
  // The destination for the result of the query.
  QXmlResultItems result;

  //------------------------------
  // Evaluate the query.
  query.evaluateTo( &result );
  if ( result.hasError() )
  {
    qDebug( "Query evaluation failed" );
    return foundNodes;
  }

  //------------------------------
  // The result of the query.
  qDebug( "Query result:" );
  while ( !result.next().isNull() )
  {
    QXmlNodeModelIndex index = result.current().toNodeModelIndex();
    QDomNode node = model.toDomNode( index );
    qDebug( "  %d %s: %s", node.nodeType(), qPrintable( node.nodeName() ), qPrintable( node.nodeValue() ) );
    foundNodes << node;
  }

  return foundNodes;
}
```

In my application, I load an XML file, and use the above utility function to search it.

```
//------------------------------
// The path of the XML file.
QString path = "settings.xml";

//------------------------------
// Open the file.
QFile file( path );
if ( !file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
{
  qDebug( "Failed to open '%s': %s", qPrintable( path ), qPrintable( file.errorString() ) );
  return;
}

//------------------------------
// Load the file into a document.
QDomDocument doc;
QString error;
int line;
int column;
if ( !doc.setContent( &file, &error, &line, &column ) )
{
  qDebug( "%s(%d,%d): %s", qPrintable( path ), line, column, qPrintable( error ) );
  return;
}

//------------------------------
// The document root element.
QDomElement rootElem = doc.documentElement();

//------------------------------
// Search for an element whose name attribute has a certain value.
QString name = "Alice";
QString xpath = QString( "setting[@name='%1']" ).arg( name );
QList<QDomNode> foundNodes = findNodes( doc, rootElem, xpath );

//------------------------------
// Did I find it?
if ( foundNodes.size() > 0 )
{
  QDomElement foundElem = foundNodes.at( 0 ).toElement();

  // Do something with that element.      
  ...
}
```

The example XML content to search.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<settings>
  <setting name="Bob">12</setting>
  <setting name="Carol">34</setting>
  <setting name="Ted">56</setting>
  <setting name="Alice">78</setting>
</settings>
```

Comment: The links above aren't valid anymore, I found the source here(https://github.com/rubenbe/QDomNodeModel)

Comment: The links are working today for me.  Maybe it was a temporary problem.

Comment: Could you update your answer for Qt6?

Comment: @8Observer8: No, I am not using Qt version 6.

Comment: @MikeFinch, thank you for your answer. Looks like XPath has been removed from Qt6 along with the QtXmlPatterns module. I had to use QDomDocument instead of XPath.